# dynamic ajax bootstrap modalbox not work in action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code for showing dynamic data in a bootstrap modal box using `$.ajax` and `json`.

JS:

```
$(function() {

    $('.push').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '<?PHP echo SITE;?>controller/booksdetails.php', // in here you should put your query 
            dataType: "json",
            data = {
                'bookid': id,
                'csrf_token': <?php echo $token; ?>
            },
            success: function(r) {
                // now you can show output in your modal 
                $('#bookdetails').modal({
                        backdrop: 'static',
                        keyboard: false
                    }) // put your modal id 
                $('.something').show().html(r);
            }
        });


    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="241" class="push info" title="Full details">show details</a>

<div id="bookdetails" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body text-justify">
               <div class="something" style="display:none;">

             </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"> close</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

But in reality when I click on the link, the modal and data are not shown! How can I fix the problem and show a value in my modal?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kwv3h8jv/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several typo mistakes:

```
'csrf_token': <?php echo $token; ?>
```

Should be:

```
 'csrf_token': '<?php echo $token; ?>'
```

String must be quoted.

Also:

```
data = {
    'bookid': id,
    'csrf_token': <?php echo $token; ?>
},
```

Should be:

```
data: {
    'bookid': id,
    'csrf_token': <?php echo $token; ?>
},
```

Property assignment of an object is performed with `:` not with `=` operator.

I have mocked your `ajax` reuqest and fixed typos mentioned above. Your code works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/kwv3h8jv/2/